# Late 1960s-early 1970s book called the moon game

Tags: identification-request

This book was read to me often. It had a story & delightful pictures. It featured a white kitten playing with the moon both in the sky & on the ground in puddles. It was around in the 1960s.

Comment: Welcome to Literature Stack Exchange, take our [tour]! Please have a look through the [identification-request wiki](/tags/identification-request/info) and, if any of the prompts there jog your memory, please [edit] further information into your question. For example, where did you get this book from? (Even a geographical location may help). What language was it in? Do you remember anything about the cover? What kind of book was this (paperback, hardcover, board book, etc.)? How large was it, both in page count/thickness and cover area? And so on - any detail may be the crucial one!

Answer (score 6):

There's *The Moon Game* by Albertine Deletaille.

[Worldcat.org](https://www.worldcat.org/title/moon-game/oclc/50914092) (it is good resource for searches when title is remembered) summary is:

> A white kitten goes searching for milk by the light of the moon and
> finds a new home.

I found YouTube video of the French original: [Chat lune](https://youtu.be/wRZZ3oMNvQc).

Comment: Published in 1960, another confirming piece of info.

Answer (score 2):

Your description suggests the children's books of the Russian illustrator Grigorʹevič Suteev (Григорьевич Сутеев , 1903–1993).  Most of these are written by Suteev himself, but some are instead written by Mihail Plâckovskij (Михаил Пляцковский).

The books are made of various short stories, all with delightful pictures indeed.  In many of the books, the characters are talking animals.  There is a story about a cat who finds that a piece of the moon must have fallen from the sky to the roof, and is now brightly shining there.  It turns out to be just a piece of broken glass that reflects the moon.  I believe there's also a story about a dog who tries to catch the reflection of the moon in a pond.

I don't know of a book or story with “The moon game” as the title though.